# Multiple Map Markers with Individual InfoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My skill with closures is not that great, I am attempting to keep a reference to each of the InfoWindows for use later but seem unable to move on from this spot. All that happens is that the same InfoWindow opens no matter which marker I click. Don't worry about the {{}} Django templating code thats fine.

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            var map;
            var myLatlng;
            var marker = [];
            var infowindow = [];
            var map_markers = [];

            {% for map_marker in map_markers %}
            map_markers.push({
                'lat':{{map_marker.latitude}},
                'lng':{{map_marker.longitude}},
                'icon':{% if map_marker.icon %}'{{map_marker.icon.url}}'{% else %}''{% endif %},
                'info':{% if map_marker.info %}'{{map_marker.info.strip|safe|escapejs}}'{% else %}''{% endif %},
            });
            {% endfor %}

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: {{map_settings.zoom}},
                center: new google.maps.LatLng({{map_settings.latitude}}, {{map_settings.longitude}})
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            for (i in map_markers){

                myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( map_markers[i].lat , map_markers[i].lng );

                marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Marker',
                    icon: map_markers[i].icon
                });

                if ( map_markers[i].info ){

                    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: map_markers[i].info
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
                        infowindow[i].open(map,marker[i]);
                    });

                }
            }

        });
```

Would be great to move on from this problem as I've been going round in circles. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please attach a working example using JSFiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: You don't _have_ to use closures.  You could store the infowindow content in a (custom) member of the marker.  I don't see any attempt at a closure in the posted code.

Comment: I attempted a closure but didn'tget very far. I am assuming that the element of infowindow[i].open(map,marker[i]); is being over written.
JSFiddle not used that before will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... added the following function

```
            function marker_click(marker,infowindow){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            }
```

and then called it...

```
marker_click(marker[i], infowindow[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use member variables of the marker rather than function closure.  Add a (custom) member to the marker (say iWcontent):

```
marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   title: 'Marker',
   icon: map_markers[i].icon,
   iWcontent:  map_markers[i].info
});
```

Use that in the marker click function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
   infowindow.setContent(this.iWcontent);
   infowindow.open(map,this);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o61b4Lhn/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var map_markers = [];
var marker = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            map_markers.push({
                'lat':45,
                'lng':-75,
                'icon':null,
                'info':'{{0}}'
            });
            map_markers.push({
                'lat':45.5,
                'lng':-75.5,
                'icon':null,
                'info':'{{1}}'
            });

function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(45, -75)
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            for (i in map_markers){

                myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( map_markers[i].lat , map_markers[i].lng );

                marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Marker',
                    icon: map_markers[i].icon,
                    iWcontent:  map_markers[i].info
                });

                if ( map_markers[i].info ){

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(this.iWcontent);
                        infowindow.open(map,this);
                    });

                }
            }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```